# Drop duplicates in a DF for specific values

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe, trying to drop duplicates, though only for a specific value, after sorting e.g. DF looks like

```
Fruit   value
apple   1
orange  2
pear    1
pear    2
pear    3
```

I'd like to drop duplicates only if the value is pear, retaining the highest value for pear.

I have split my current DF into 2:
1. With apple and orange - DF1
2.With pear - DF2
3. Sorted descending
4. Dropped pear 2 and pear 1
5. Concatenated DF1 and DF2

This looks quite cumbersome, so wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this.

```
Fruit   value
apple   1
orange  2
pear    3
```

Comment: A question (perhaps not related to the problem): Did you choose pear only after inspecting the data manually? i.e. if orange had more than 1 row would you want to drop duplicates for oranges as well?

Comment: Anything other than pear can have as many rows as possible, doesn't matter. It's only the pears I'm interested to remove if duplicate, after having sorted, keeping the highest value against pear

Answer (score 2):

In your case  split them then `drop_duplicates`, then `concat` it back

```
df1=df.loc[df.Fruit.eq('pear')]
pd.concat([df.drop(df1.index),df1.sort_values('value').drop_duplicates('Fruit',keep='last')]).sort_index()
Out[111]: 
    Fruit  value
0   apple      1
1  orange      2
4    pear      3
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need two conditions here. One for duplicate checking (retaining the max value), and the other for the fruit:

```
m1 = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False).duplicated('Fruit')
m2 = df['Fruit'].eq('pear')

df[~(m1 & m2)]

    Fruit  value
0   apple      1
1  orange      2
4    pear      3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this after sorting

1. Sorting in descending order to make highest value on top
2. As you need to remove only when **Fruit =='pear'**

```
df.sort_values(by='value',ascending=[False],inplace=True)
df = df[~((df['fruit'].duplicated()) &(df['fruit']=='pear'))]
df.sort_values(by='value',ascending=[True],inplace=True)
```

Comment: @cs95 yeah I was writing when you posted the answer

Comment: @L.F. Thanks for the suggestion ,kindly check again I have updated the answer

Comment: @tawab_shakeel Yep, now it is a complete answer that can help future readers.

Comment: Thank you. This would make it much simpler for me

Comment: @RajeshD upvote or approve answer so that more people can benefit from it

Comment: Hi tawab_shakeel , I tried this in the code. Gave a syntax errror, think its the [ howerver after correcting , it gives me just the pear, I was expecting 3 rows df.sort_values(by='value',ascending=[False],inplace=True)
df[~(df['Fruit'].duplicated()) &(df['Fruit']=='pear')]

Comment: @RajeshD sorry I have updated the answer there was an issue of round brackets

Comment: @RajeshD kindly check it again

Comment: Thank you . I was also expecting pear to be the last on the list whereas its coming as first. Guess it needs some sorting ?

Comment: @RajeshD yes i have added the final sorting pear would be in last